# Integer Array combination for getting sum value

Tags: arrays, integer, combinations

I am having array of 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128...... etc (Note: using this array we can get any number by adding exact combination of array values)so if i give number 9 it should return output as 8 + 1.few more.for 50, 32 + 16 + 2.I need a logic for this

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you don't want do get a million downvotes, please read this - 
http://sscce.org/ and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask , and then come back.  If you want someone to take time out of their busy day to help you, you should show some level of effort in writing your question.

"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist